# VS Find/Replace Regex to reposition pairs of characters

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace, character

Need help with regex, basically title^ says it all, but to be more precise for my case, I got tons of "strings" with this HEX pattern:

```
(0x00000000)
```

Now I'd like to find all cases of it and after x reposition 2-char pairs with additional changes, so that regex should do something like this:

```
(0x11AA55BB) => (AA, 55, BB, 11)

(0x1AB23CD4) => (B2, 3C, D4, 1A)
```

I guess it should be something like this (??? => is the part I would like you to help me with):

> ```
> Find: \\(0x???\\)
>
> Replace: \\(\\2\\,\\3\\,\\4\\,\\1\\)
> ```

Comment: Just to be clear, you're talking about a find and replace in the Visual Studio IDE and not programmatically in code, right?

Comment: yes - in VS Find/Replace as the title says

Comment: so what's not working with what you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Visual Studio's find/replace dialogue but here's a regex that does the job:

```
\(0x([\dA-F]{2})([\dA-F]{2})([\dA-F]{2})([\dA-F]{2})\)
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/aP2uV1/1)

So `[\dA-F]` means *"match a digit (`\d`) or a letter between `A` and `F`"*. Then you can say how many matches with `{2}` and you place them in separate capture-groups with the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, will accept as answer in few min, when it will allow me to ;)